# Rails Stripe Checkout: Card modal not opening, stripeToken null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, stripe-payments, stripe.js

I'm trying to add Stripe payments to my Rails app.

I've followed their [Rails Checkout Guide](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails) guide exactly, but the checkout modal is not popping up to collect the card information and therefore the card token returned is null when trying to charge the customer.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can you help?

**Edit: I've verified that my code works in another app.** I now believe that the problem is with using **Vue** on the front end. It seems like Vue is denying Stripe's JS the opportunity to run and submits the form automatically when the modal trigger button is pressed.

**Edit #2: Gave up and created a customized Vue form with Elements instead of checkout. [This tutorial](https://alligator.io/vuejs/stripe-elements-vue-integration/) guided me if anybody else finds it useful.

My code is as follows:

```
# app/views/charges/new.html.erb

<%= form_tag charges_path do %>
<article>
    <% if flash[:error].present? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <label class="amount">
    <span>Amount: $5.00</span>
    </label>
</article>
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
    data-description="A month's subscription"
    data-amount="500"
    data-locale="auto"></script>
<% end %>
```

.

```
# app/controllers/charges_controller.rb

def create
    # Amount in cents
    @amount = 500
    puts "token = "
    puts params[:stripeToken]
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => params[:stripeEmail],
      :source  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => @amount,
      :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
      :currency    => 'usd'
    )

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
end
```

Comment: If I run your code w/o the rails components, it works as expected.  Which makes me think there is something wrong with how it's being rendered.  I suggest you open your console and see how your browser is rendering this section of your page.  Also look for errors in your console.  It's likely a small extra space in the API Key or something.  https://jsfiddle.net/g2dyag1y/